# CAR-T therapy for cardiac sarcoidosis?

Tags: immune-system, cardiology, scar-tissue-scars, inflammation

Do you know whether CAR-T therapy to replace fibrotic cells in the heart might apply to scarring from cardiac sarcoidosis?

The articles below are from Penn research that shows they are able to replace fibrotic cells in murine hearts that were damaged by injury. I'm trying to understand if the scarring created by granulomas in cardiac sarcoidosis could be replaced with healthy tissue in the same way.

Article:
https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abm0594

Layman's summary:
https://www.pennmedicine.org/news/news-releases/2022/january/vaccine-like-mrna-injection-can-be-used-to-make-car-t-cells-in-the-body

Answer (score 1):

I talked with an author of the paper and the answer is, in principle, yes. Sarcoidosis is on their radar.